# How can I have multiple Email Actions in Ninja Forms

Tags: wordpress, email, ninja-forms

I tried to add multiple Email actions in Ninja forms, but after doing so none of my actions are working. It's only working with single email actions.
I want to send form submitted data on multiple Email accounts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send to multiple email addresses by separating them by a comma and/or bcc other email addresses.

In the Email Notification Action, add as many email addresses as you want in the TO field, separated by a comma.

```
email@address.com,email2@address.com,address3@address.com
```

To blind cc someone, click on the ADVANCED section which is underneath the EMAIL MESSAGE content block.  This will expand advanced options for the notification action.

You can enter email addresses in the BCC field just like the TO field.

Comment: Its good for static email ids, BUT How to send email to dynamic email ids?

Comment: Ravi - Great question.  Unfortunately I haven't worked in WP for a few years, so I can only guess.

Do you mean dynamic emails from a form?  If so, I would think you could use syntax like
{field:email},email2@address.com

That's just a guess though.  Hope that helps!